# SQL: How to get Max Order number row from multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I Select Max Order_number row from given multiple rows? per example below results `9010305604` is the max number. I need to select `9010305604`row

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
            CUST.PRIMARY_EMAIL_ADDRESS [EMAIL],
            OD.ORDER_NO [ORDER_NUMBER],
            CUST.MASTER_CUSTOMER_ID [CUSTOMER ID],
            CUST.SUB_CUSTOMER_ID,
            CUST.USR_ORIG_JOIN_DATE,
            OD.CYCLE_END_DATE
            , OD.RATE_CODE
            ,OD.CYCLE_BEGIN_DATE
            --, OD.ORIGINAL_ORDER_NO      
FROM    CUSTOMER CUST (NOLOCK) 
        INNER JOIN ORDER_DETAIL OD (NOLOCK) 
            ON CUST.MASTER_CUSTOMER_ID = OD.SHIP_MASTER_CUSTOMER_ID 
            AND OD.SHIP_SUB_CUSTOMER_ID = CUST.SUB_CUSTOMER_ID
        INNER JOIN ORDER_MASTER OM (NOLOCK) 
            ON OD.ORDER_NO = OM.ORDER_NO 
        INNER JOIN PRODUCT PROD
            ON [PROD].[PRODUCT_ID] = [OD].[PRODUCT_ID]
WHERE            OD.SUBSYSTEM = 'MBR'
           
            AND OD.PRODUCT_CODE    IN ('PROFESSIONAL')
            AND OD.LINE_STATUS_CODE    = 'A'
   --         AND OD.CYCLE_BEGIN_DATE <= GETDATE() 
          AND OD.CYCLE_END_DATE >= GETDATE() 
            --AND OD.ORIGINAL_ORDER_NO IS NULL         
            AND CUST.PRIMARY_EMAIL_ADDRESS IS NOT NULL        
            AND CUST.USR_ORIG_JOIN_DATE >cast(DATEADD(day, -120,GETDATE()) AS DATE)            
            AND    OM.USR_BULK_ORDER_NO IS NULL
            AND MASTER_CUSTOMER_ID = '4655302'


 EMAIL                 ORDER_NUMBER CUSTOMER ID SUB_CUSTOMER_ID USR_ORIG_JOIN_DATE  CYCLE_END_DATE  RATE_CODE   CYCLE_BEGIN_DATE
sannyastari@gmail.com   9010305603  4655302 0   2020-11-21 00:00:00.000 2020-12-31 00:00:00.000 1YR 2020-11-21 00:00:00.000
sannyastari@gmail.com   9010305604  4655302 0   2020-11-21 00:00:00.000 2021-12-31 00:00:00.000 1YR 2021-01-01 00:00:00.000
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a `TOP` query?

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 1
    CUST.PRIMARY_EMAIL_ADDRESS [EMAIL],
    OD.ORDER_NO [ORDER_NUMBER],
    ...

(rest of your query)

ORDER BY
    OD.ORDER_NO DESC;
```